# how to get all objects by instance in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need all objects, like `SomethingModel.objects.all()` for instance.

```
class SometingModel(model.Model):

    def get_all_objects(self):
        __[what should i do?]__
        return queryset
```

for example,

```
queryset = SomethingModel.objects.all()
queryset_by_instance = SomethingModel.objects.get(pk=1).get_all_objects()

queryset == queryset_by_instance <===== True {doesn't matter order}
```

---

I need this for data extraction, like

```
def get_filtered_data(object, object_attribute, min, max):
    return object.get_all_objects().filter(object_attribute__lte=max)\
        .filter(object_attribute__gte=min)
```

Comment: How about `instance._meta.model.objects.all()`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `__class__` to get the model name and then get all the objects.

```
In [1]: my_instance.__class__
Out[1]: app_name.models.SometingModel # returns the model 

In[2]: my_instance.__class__.objects.all()
Out[2]: [..list of objects..] # returns queryset
```

Another option is to use `_meta.model` which [@Spectras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3212865/spectras) also mentioned above.

```
In[3]: my_instance._meta.model
Out[3]: app_name.models.SometingModel # returns the model

In[4]: my_instance._meta.model.objects.all()
Out[4]: [..list of objects..] # returns queryset
```

Then in your models, you can do something like:

```
class SometingModel(model.Model):

    def get_all_objects(self):
        queryset = self._meta.model.objects.all()
        # can use the below method also
        # queryset = self.__class__.objects.all()   
        return queryset
```